# SQL Counting Records with Count and Having

Tags: sql, count, having

I'm having problems with what I thought was a simple query to count records:

```
SELECT req_ownerid, count(req_status_lender) AS total6 
FROM bor_requests
WHERE (req_status_lender = 0 AND req_status_borrower = 0) OR 
      (req_status_lender = 1 AND req_status_borrower = 1)
GROUP BY req_ownerid 
HAVING req_ownerid = 70
```

I thought this would count all the records where (req_status_lender = 0 AND req_status_borrower = 0) and (req_status_lender = 1 AND req_status_borrower = 1) and then give me the total but it only gives me the total for either (req_status_lender = 0 AND req_status_borrower = 0) or (req_status_lender = 1 AND req_status_borrower = 1).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `HAVING` clause only to limit on something that's been aggregated in your query above - e.g. if you want to select all those rows where a `SUM(....)` or `COUNT(...)` is larger than say 5, then you'd use `HAVING SUM(...) > 5`

What you're doing here is a standard `WHERE` clause - add it there!

```
SELECT req_ownerid, count(req_status_lender) AS total6 
FROM bor_requests
WHERE req_ownerid = 70
      AND ((req_status_lender = 0 AND req_status_borrower = 0) OR 
           (req_status_lender = 1 AND req_status_borrower = 1))
GROUP BY req_ownerid
```