# Get results depending on time-based conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

A very simple representation of my problem is:

Reviews

```
| mentor_id | mentee_id | status   | created    |
| 1         | 2         | active   | 2014-08-13 |
| 1         | 2         | inactive | 2014-08-20 |
| 1         | 2         | inactive | 2014-08-27 |
| 1         | 3         | inactive | 2014-08-20 |
| 1         | 2         | inactive | 2014-09-03 |
```

User Table

```
| id | first_name | last_name |
| 1  | Ivan       | Pietro    |
| 2  | Alexander  | Summers   |
| 3  | Mark       | Xavier    |
```

Mentorship Table

```
| id | mentee_id | mentor_id | created    |
| 1  | 2         | 1         | 2014-08-06 |
| 2  | 3         | 1         | 2014-08-06 |
```

`mentor_id` and `mentee_id` are ids of the users table.

I want to get the `users.id`, `users.first_name` and `users.last_name` of the mentees(`user` table) that have a `status` of `inactive` for the last 14 days after they were created in the mentorship table.

Comment: Where are these reviews stored? You need to select w/e you want, JOIN users table on mentee_id and then order by created and limit by 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Counting Records with Count and Having](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912792/sql-counting-records-with-count-and-having)

Comment: reviews are stored in the reviews table

Comment: This database design doesn't seem to be normalized. You have a relationship between mentor and mentee in both the Mentorship and Reviews table. I would eliminate that before proceeding and replace the mentor_id & mentee_id columns in Reviews with a mentorship_id column that is a FK to the Mentorship table.

Comment: I modified the question since I think @bodi0 was confused. I also added more information.

Comment: Thanks @BrettWolfington However, I can't do much about it right now since its the current structure.

Comment: Can you add a list of what records you are aiming to obtain with the ideal query? Thanks.

Comment: @Raad, done! users.id, users.first_name and users.last_name

Comment: @ThorpeObazee - I was actually looking for some example output, but see if my answer does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't crystal clear, but I think you are asking for:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT u.*
FROM    reviews r
JOIN    mentorship m
        ON m.mentee_id = r.mentee_id AND m.mentor_id = r.mentor_id
JOIN    user u
        ON u.id = r.mentee_id
WHERE   r.status =  'inactive'
AND     DATEDIFF(r.created, m.created) >= 14
```

This would give you:

```
id first_name last_name
-- ---------- ----------
2  Alexander  Summers
3  Mark       Xavier
```

It's difficult to know if this is what you are after because the dataset is limited (there are only 2 mentees anyway).
Hopefully it is!

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
  select user.id,user.first_name,user.last_name,max(Reviews.created) RCreated, Mentorship.created  MCreated
    from Reviews 
    inner join User on Reviews.mentee_id=USer.id 
    inner join Mentorship on Reviews.mentee_id=Mentorship.mentee_id
    where status='inactive'  
    group by User.id 
    having  DATEDIFF(RCreated, MCreated) >= 14
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfc71/26

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (CURDATE() is for MySQL, you have to look into it if you use a different SQL).

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users, reviews
WHERE reviews.mentee_id = users.id AND reviews.status = 'inactive' AND DATEDIFF(reviews.created, CURDATE()) >= 14;
```

Comment: You're close but it has to be the date the mentorship record were created instead of `CURDATE()`